# Showing JQuery Toast's alert in ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, toast

Using ASP MVC and JQuery, I am trying to show a Toast error's alert if the Email or Password is wrong.

The problem is that I am using a Tempdata to show the message and I didn't success to include the toast jquery in the Tempdata.

PS : The toast's alert works perfectly in the others views where I don't use the tempdata to show the message.

So this is what I've tried :

Controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Login(FormCollection fc, string LastName, string Email)
    {
        int res = dblayer.Admin_Login(fc["Email"], fc["Password"]);
        if (res == 1)
        {
            Session["currentUser"] = Email;
            string z = Email;
            connection();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Email from Client", con);

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                con.Close();
            }
            foreach (string x in result)
            {
                if (x == z)
                {

                    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand($"select LastName from Client WHERE Email= '{x}' ", con);
                    con.Open();
                    string y = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    con.Close();
                    Session["currentUser"] = y;

                }
            } 

            //Session["currentUser"] = LastName;
            return RedirectToAction("Profil", "Client");
            Session.RemoveAll();


        }
        else {

            TempData["msg"] = " Email or Password is wrong !";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

    }
```

View :

```
<link href="~/Content/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/scripts/toastr.js"></script>
<div class="w3layouts-main" style="background-image:url('/template/web/images/bg3.jpg'); margin-top:50px;">
   <h2>Login Now</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <input value="E-MAIL"  name="Email" type="email" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-Mail';}" />
                <input value="PASSWORD" name="Password" type="password" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'password';}" />

                <div class="clear"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="login" name="login">

            }
</div>



 @section scripts {
    @{
        if (TempData["msg"] != null)
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                toastr.error("", "Email or password is wrong !)");
                window.location = '#2249506';

            </script>
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. It should show the toastr alert as long as you have the files needed for that loaded.

Comment: @Shyju I have the files, and I used the same call in another view, it is works but in this view it shows the classic alert of the browser

Comment: Because your code is telling to do so. You have an alert when the TempData is not null. Change that to `toastr.error` call

Comment: I did it, when I enter a wrong password, nothing happens and I have this Jquery error : Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

Comment: That means the libarary is not loaded **before** using it. Make sure your code is executed after the library is loaded

Comment: @Shyju I understand, but how ? Shall I put the definition of toast in the top of the code or ?

Comment: Is your code inside a `@section Scripts` section block ?

Comment: no isn't and my script <script src="~/scripts/toastr.js"></script> is in the bottom of my code

Comment: move your code to `@section Scripts` in the view and include the toastr library  in layout before calling the `RenderSection("scritpts")`

Comment: @Shyju I have edit the code, can you take a look please